# Как показать блоки по отдельности

Tags: javascript

Имеется раздел с 3-я блоками (каждый блок состоит из заголовка и текста(текст скрывается классом), как можно сделать так, что бы при нажатии на заголовок удалялся класс и показывался только текст в одном блоке, а не во всех как у меня. В js очень слаб реализовал так:

```js
var caption = document.querySelectorAll(".mywork__caption");
var discription = document.querySelectorAll(".mywork__description");

if (discription) {
  for (var i = 0; i < discription.length; i++) {
    discription[i].classList.add("mywork__description--close");
  }
};


for (var i = 0; i < caption.length; i++) {
  caption[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < discription.length; i++) {
      discription[i].classList.remove("mywork__description--close");
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<section class="mywork">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="caption__left"></div>
    <b>Мои работы</b>
    <div class="caption__right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mywork__container">
    <div class="mywork__all mywork__all--mishka">
      <img src="img/mishka-index-desktop.jpg" alt="" height="185" width="280">
      <b class="mywork__caption">“Мишка”</b>
      <div class="mywork__description">
        <p>Вёрстка сайта магазина “Мишка”, игрушек ручной работы</p>
        <p>Описание выполненных работ:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Вёрстка: адаптивная + резина</li>
          <li>Использована адаптивная графика</li>
          <li>Оптимизирована загрузка шрифтов</li>
          <li>Оптиизация изображений под экраны с большой плотностью пикселей, а также использование новейшего формата от Google .webp, что позволяет значительно уменьшить вес изображений и следовательно увеличить скорость загрузки страниц</li>
          <li>Оптимизированная векторная графика</li>
          <li>Вёрстка без использования Фреймворков</li>
          <li>Валидная вёрстка</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mywork__all mywork__all--nerds">
      <img src="img/nerds-index.png" alt="" height="185" width="280">
      <b class="mywork__caption">“nerds”</b>
      <div class="mywork__description">
        <p>Вёрстка сайта магазина “Nerds”, сайта по продаже шаблонов</p>
        <p>Описание выполненых работ:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Фиксированая вёрстка</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна векторная графика</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна растравая графика</li>
          <li>Вёрстка без использования Фреймворков</li>
          <li>Валидная вёрстка</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mywork__all mywork__all--gllacy">
      <img src="img/gllacy-index-1200.png" alt="" height="185" width="280">
      <b class="mywork__caption">“Gllacy”</b>
      <div class="mywork__description">
        <p>Вёрстка сайта магазина “Gllacy”, сайта по продаже мароженого</p>
        <p>Описание выполненых работ:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Фиксированая вёрстка</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна векторная графика</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна растравая графика</li>
          <li>Вёрстка без использования Фреймворков</li>
          <li>Валидная вёрстка</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

зарание спасибо)))

Comment: Добавь `html` тоже...

Answer (score 3):

Надеюсь, я правильно понял задачу...

```js
var caption = document.querySelectorAll(".mywork__caption");
var discription = document.querySelectorAll(".mywork__description");
for (let i = 0; i < caption.length; i++) {
  caption[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (discription[i].classList.contains('mywork__description--close')) {
      discription[i].classList.remove('mywork__description--close');
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < discription.length; i++) {
        discription[i].classList.remove('mywork__description--close');
      }
      discription[i].classList.add('mywork__description--close');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.mywork__description {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
  height: 0px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.mywork__description--close {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 230px;
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

```html
<section class="mywork">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="caption__left"></div>
    <b>Мои работы</b>
    <div class="caption__right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mywork__container">
    <div class="mywork__all mywork__all--mishka">
      <img src="img/mishka-index-desktop.jpg" alt="" height="185" width="280">
      <b class="mywork__caption">“Мишка”</b>
      <div class="mywork__description">
        <p>Вёрстка сайта магазина “Мишка”, игрушек ручной работы</p>
        <p>Описание выполненных работ:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Вёрстка: адаптивная + резина</li>
          <li>Использована адаптивная графика</li>
          <li>Оптимизирована загрузка шрифтов</li>
          <li>Оптиизация изображений под экраны с большой плотностью пикселей, а также использование новейшего формата от Google .webp, что позволяет значительно уменьшить вес изображений и следовательно увеличить скорость загрузки страниц</li>
          <li>Оптимизированная векторная графика</li>
          <li>Вёрстка без использования Фреймворков</li>
          <li>Валидная вёрстка</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mywork__all mywork__all--nerds">
      <img src="img/nerds-index.png" alt="" height="185" width="280">
      <b class="mywork__caption">“nerds”</b>
      <div class="mywork__description">
        <p>Вёрстка сайта магазина “Nerds”, сайта по продаже шаблонов</p>
        <p>Описание выполненых работ:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Фиксированая вёрстка</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна векторная графика</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна растравая графика</li>
          <li>Вёрстка без использования Фреймворков</li>
          <li>Валидная вёрстка</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mywork__all mywork__all--gllacy">
      <img src="img/gllacy-index-1200.png" alt="" height="185" width="280">
      <b class="mywork__caption">“Gllacy”</b>
      <div class="mywork__description">
        <p>Вёрстка сайта магазина “Gllacy”, сайта по продаже мароженого</p>
        <p>Описание выполненых работ:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Фиксированая вёрстка</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна векторная графика</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна растравая графика</li>
          <li>Вёрстка без использования Фреймворков</li>
          <li>Валидная вёрстка</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Изменил, пример, забыл, что должен открываться по нажатию на заголовок

Answer (score 2):

ну вообще, если по вашей проблеме, то при клике не нужен цикл. 
просто меняйте класс у нужного

```
for (var i = 0; i < caption.length; i++) {
  caption[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("mywork__description--close")
  })
}
```

Но я бы вам рекомендовал не много изменить подход, а именно:
в качестве контейнера выбрать mywork__all и ему менять класс. тогда у вас будет доступ к заголовку (можете менять цвет или что-то ещё).
Так же изначально скрывать блок css'ом, и добавлять класс open и через него уже открывать

```js
var caption = document.querySelectorAll(".mywork__caption");
var discription = document.querySelectorAll(".mywork__all");

if (discription) {
  for (var i = 0; i < discription.length; i++) {
    caption[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var $this = this.closest('.mywork__all');
    $this.classList.toggle("mywork__description--open")
    for (var i = 0; i < discription.length; i++) {
        if($this != discription[i]) {
          discription[i].classList.remove("mywork__description--open");
        }
      }
    })
  }
};
```

```css
.mywork__description {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s all;
}
.mywork__description--open .mywork__description {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.mywork__description--open .mywork__caption {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="mywork">
  <div class="caption">
    <div class="caption__left"></div>
    <b>Мои работы</b>
    <div class="caption__right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mywork__container">
    <div class="mywork__all mywork__all--mishka">
      <img src="img/mishka-index-desktop.jpg" alt="" height="185" width="280">
      <b class="mywork__caption">“Мишка”</b>
      <div class="mywork__description">
        <p>Вёрстка сайта магазина “Мишка”, игрушек ручной работы</p>
        <p>Описание выполненных работ:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Вёрстка: адаптивная + резина</li>
          <li>Использована адаптивная графика</li>
          <li>Оптимизирована загрузка шрифтов</li>
          <li>Оптиизация изображений под экраны с большой плотностью пикселей, а также использование новейшего формата от Google .webp, что позволяет значительно уменьшить вес изображений и следовательно увеличить скорость загрузки страниц</li>
          <li>Оптимизированная векторная графика</li>
          <li>Вёрстка без использования Фреймворков</li>
          <li>Валидная вёрстка</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mywork__all mywork__all--nerds">
      <img src="img/nerds-index.png" alt="" height="185" width="280">
      <b class="mywork__caption">“nerds”</b>
      <div class="mywork__description">
        <p>Вёрстка сайта магазина “Nerds”, сайта по продаже шаблонов</p>
        <p>Описание выполненых работ:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Фиксированая вёрстка</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна векторная графика</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна растравая графика</li>
          <li>Вёрстка без использования Фреймворков</li>
          <li>Валидная вёрстка</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mywork__all mywork__all--gllacy">
      <img src="img/gllacy-index-1200.png" alt="" height="185" width="280">
      <b class="mywork__caption">“Gllacy”</b>
      <div class="mywork__description">
        <p>Вёрстка сайта магазина “Gllacy”, сайта по продаже мароженого</p>
        <p>Описание выполненых работ:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Фиксированая вёрстка</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна векторная графика</li>
          <li>Оптимизированна растравая графика</li>
          <li>Вёрстка без использования Фреймворков</li>
          <li>Валидная вёрстка</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))

Comment: Если не сложно можешь еще подсказать, как сделать что бы плавно менялся при удалении класс, а то транситион не работает и анимация как-то некоректо работает

Comment: тогда меняй min-height. transition на display не работает. Код подправил

Comment: но если же использовать фикс высоту то не будет проходить проверку на переполнение, а если делать max высоту больше чем требуется, то происходит задержка transition

Comment: Артём, я вижу несколько вариантов:
1) использовать max-height (я не писал про height - с ним не подойдёт) - с небольших запасом. сейчас так сделано в примере - вы там видите задержку ? 
2) плавное появление через opacity - но прыгать всё равно будет
3) в отношении появления блока отойти от css и использовать js (почему бы в таком случае не использовать jquery )
других вариантов я не вижу. сам использую - для мелких первый вариант, для более сложных 3-тий